# Find the records with diagonal occurrence in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all the records that fulfill following condition: all Bs that have reverse substitution.

In this case S1 and S2 are the records fulfilling the condition:

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column3
B1        S1        AS1
B1        AS1       S1
B2        S2        AS2
B2        As2       AS3
B2        As3       S2
B3        S3        AS3
B3        As3       ASS3
```

Desired Output:

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column3
B1        S1        AS1
B1        AS1       S1
B2        S2        AS2
B2        As2       AS3
B2        As3       S2
```

The records of Column 2 are replaced by records of column3. see AS1 has replaced S1 in record second row. Now if S1 Replaces AS1 again this is reverse substitution. Among B1,B2,...BN I need all B's that fulfill this condition. So I am trying something that checks column2 and column3 from row with same Bx but different row.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Comment: So what's the expected result (with the given sample data)?

Comment: define reverse substitution.

Comment: Don't AS1 and AS2 fulfill the requirements?

Comment: Why do you expect `S2`?

Comment: I have edited question as per your queries please check now

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
WHERE column2 like '%'+column3+'%' OR column3 like '%'+column2+'%'
```

Here, the `WHERE` condition will look if value of column2 is contained in column3, and vice versa.

---

I think you are only looking if column2 is contained in column3. If so, then there is no need of the second condition, ie., you only need to write this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
WHERE column2 like '%'+column3+'%'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: actually this compare records from same row. I am looking for something that checks column2 and column3 from row with same Bx but different row.

Comment: Is s2 in reverse substituted ?

Comment: Yes S2 is also reverse substituted.

Comment: You can check if the count of each values in column2 equals count of values in column3, for distinct column1. I am not able to make a loop for that right now. But I'll try.